# Django, not able to load image, but css is loaded

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static

I m able to load css file based on the tutorial provided by djangoproject but images are not getting loaded.
Here is the file structure:
appname/static/ mess/ img/ burger.jpg

Here is the login.html file where I m trying to load the image.

```
`<html>
 <head>
     <title>Login | Mess @ IIIT Sri City</title>
     {% load staticfiles %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'mess/css/style.css' %}"> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'mess/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="container">
         <div id="left-content" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         {% load staticfiles %}
         <center><img src="{% static 'mess/img/burger.jpg' %}" alt="Please Login here"></center>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                 {{ form}}
                 <input  type="submit" value="Submit" />
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
 </body>
`
```

It would be a great help if you could resolve me out of this issue.
PS: I m a beginner in Django.
Django version: 1.8
Please tell me if u need more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have {% load staticfiles %} twice on the same page?

Comment: try with {{STATIC_URL}} mess/img/burger.jpg

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio I tried that too, but it's still not loading. The irony is css files are being loaded.

Comment: in url.py have configurated staticfiles?

Comment: check the permissions of the folder where the IMG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because the folder didn't have necessary permissions and Django was unable to access it.

Answer (score 0):

in url.py have you configurated staticfiles?

```
if settings.DEBUG:  
        urlpatterns += patterns('',  
                                #REMOVE IT in production phase  
                                (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  
                                {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
          )
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes to make here. You can copy and paste the following code below for your template, and the settings below that in your urls.py:

**html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login | Mess @ IIIT Sri City</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'mess/css/style.css' %}"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'mess/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="left-content" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <center><img src="{% static 'mess/img/burger.jpg' %}" alt="Please Login here" /></center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls:**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += patterns('',) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the html, I added `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top to keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). I also made a few syntax changes to your code; very minor. In the urls, when your settings are set to `DEBUG = True`, Django will load your static images. When you go into production and `DEBUG = False`, Django no longer serves the static files. That is your server's responsibility.

I hope that helps.

If it still doesn't work, can you please post your `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'    urls.py is showing name error.    Should I import something in urls.py ?

Comment: name 'settings' is not defined

Comment: @SahalSajjad At the top, import this `from django.conf import settings`